# Does a persons weight affect their potential selection to be an astronaut?

Tags: launch, astronauts, mass, economics, astronaut-recruitment

Every extra bit of [weight cost extra to send to orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1989).  Presumably it also impacts the possible payload.

Assuming a generally healthy build, and otherwise physically able and fit person. In astronaut selection in general or for specific missions does a prospective astronaut's weight (*mass for the purist*) impact selection?

Comment: Related: [What medical conditions can impede someone from going into space?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/50/49) and [Size of Apollo era astronauts](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/2253/49) FWIW "weight" is a [perfectly legit term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_versus_weight) in this case even for the purists, since it's the gravity that defines how difficult it is to get a certain "mass" in orbit. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Space Shuttle was not specifically payload limited on most missions, such that the difference of even 100 lbs on a crew member would have mattered.  Soyuz is much the same. Perhaps earlier Mercury and Gemini missions were tighter on performance, and it might have been vaguely considered.

Height however is a bigger issue. Soyuz is quite cramped, and they needed to make some modifications to allow US astronauts, who tended to be taller than their Russian/Soviet partners, and for the female astronauts who tended to be shorter.

In addition, US space suits for EVA have limited ranges in terms of how large and how small they can be sized, which can constrain astronaut selection a bit.