# How important is the size of an astronaut?

Tags: astronauts, medical

It seems to me that weight and size would be important in choosing spacefarers for many reasons; I came across this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronaut_training) where the Chinese astronauts (taikonauts) have to be between 50 and 70 kg, which makes sense to me, but other countries don't seem to stipulate a size requirement.

I would think that it would be easier and cheaper to get the person into space if they weigh less, and could survive on less food for a given time frame so you also save on the provisions.

Cramped conditions would be less of a problem.

All else being equal, is there any reason why sending bigger people into space would be an advantage?

Comment: Space suits themselves are expensive.  If you want to be a NASA astronaut, you have to fit into the suits they have.  They most likely will not go through the expense of making a new one just for you.  You have to fit inside the launch vehicle, and be able to sit in the chair properly, and anything else you will be inside of, as well.  So, yes, these considerations are important, but I do not know a full list or good references for them.

Comment: Using the Soyez rocket they build the chair and suite specially for you.

Comment: Good point on the spacesuit, I didn't think of that. The question was more about the advantages of sending bigger people, your average science fiction space hero is around 6 ft tall and not particularly slim. Whereas the reality of space travel and perhaps humanity could be a conscious move towards smaller more efficient bodies. At the moment I can't think of any advantage to sending a bigger person.

Comment: To answer the question - can height be an advantage. Allowing a wider range of people does increase the choice of suitable candidates, so I guess this is the advantage. I read there used to be tighter restrictions on height, for example 6ft maximum for the early NASA astronauts. But these days there seems to be a wider range of shapes and sizes that are acceptable. Smaller people don't necessarily save that much weight on food, oxygen, water intake, clothing and miscellaneous equipment. And suits are a small expense compared to the costs of several years of training.

Comment: I'm unconvinced, I live in Samoa, I easily eat less than a third of what my brother in law eats yet at 80kg I'm not a third of his weight of 124kg, yet you wouldn't call him obese. That's why the question asks "All else being equal" The assumption is training etc,. is equivalent.

Comment: See [What medical conditions can impede someone from going into space?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/50/49) and [Does a person's weight effect their potential selection to be an astronaut?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/4138/49) Also related: [Size of Apollo era astronauts](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/2253/49) and some other questions tagged under [tag:health] and [tag:medical].

Comment: Astronauts are way more expensive than space suits. U.S. space suits are individually sized.

Comment: US EVA suits are put together from a selection of "generic" sizing components to best fit individual crewmembers.

Comment: I've read somewhere that it is NASA's policy to not discriminate astronauts because of size or on other grounds than fitness. Kind of a political correctness thing (one which I for once agree with).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the early days of crewed space exploration, size and weight of crew was an issue. The original batch of Soviet cosmonauts selected were restricted to 1.75m height and 72kg mass, for example, and US astronauts to 1.80m and 82kg.

As launchers got bigger and spacecraft got more complex (and roomier), these restrictions became less important because the crew represented a progressively smaller share of the mass budget.

For example, in the Mercury program, the astronaut's mass was ~5.8% of the spacecraft mass; in Gemini, the crew was ~4.3%; in Apollo earth-orbit configurations, ~1.2%.

At some point in that progression, it makes sense to start relaxing the astronaut height/mass restrictions. China's space program simply hasn't advanced far enough for them to do so yet.

As for inherent advantages of a larger crew member, all other things being equal, larger people in good health are generally stronger, which can be important during certain EVA operations. In most other criteria a smaller crew member would probably be very slightly preferable primarily due to resource consumption rates.

Comment: I expect those EVA operations to be rare, while the slight reduction in resource consumption would be a constant and over time, say a couple of years or so add up to quite a substantial reduction.  Perhaps so rare that over a lengthy period I could actually afford to have 2 smaller spacefarers to handle the EVA operation. I'm thinking long term space travel not a trip to the moon. Strength in many cases apart from weight lifting is often in practice a product of leverage, particularly in cramped quarters. You have given the best answer so far though.

Comment: I would expect that consumable usage (food, water, air) would be pretty close to linear with body mass, so there's no point at which two 75kg crewmembers would be more mass-effective than one 100kg crewmember; if you want to replace 3 100kg crewmembers with 4 75kg crewmembers, you need an extra seat, an extra sleep compartment, an extra spacesuit, and so on. I'm not saying there's no advantage in smaller crew members, just that at some point it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: I disagree, my brother in law easily out eats me by a factor of three, I'm just under 80kg, he is 124kg but not at all obese. But I didn't really put my question properly either (I thought of interplanetary missions or one way colonisation where there's also a factor of landing with a bigger gene pool) and shorter term spaceflight I agree that the difference isn't a big issue, I hadn't thought of short missions at all. All in all your answer covers the question so I'll accept it. And probably pose a new question.

Comment: @Kilisi what are your relative activity levels?  Some years back I found an exercise vs calories burned table that had columns for multiple weights spanning from small skinny people to very fat ones (IIRC a 3-4x range from min to max); and for most if not all activities listed energy consumed scaled roughly linearly with weight.  Eg, your BiL would need ~50% more energy than you to run a marathon and would also burn calories twice as fast when you're both sitting on a couch watching TV.

Comment: I probably train a bit harder than him, he's a soccer coach so pretty fit, I used to box and still train. But he's full Samoan and I'm half Samoan, so we may well have a difference there. The main difference I can see is that I stop eating when I'm no longer hungry, many people here stop eating when the foods finished.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but Shuttle height restrictions reflected the initial requirements of not restricting most of the US population and were [generous](http://www.nytimes.com/1994/07/12/science/astronaut-grows-too-tall.html): minimum of 4 ft 10 1/2 inches for mission specialists, 5 ft 4 inches for pilots and commanders, maximum of 6 ft 4 inches.

This is quite a wide range, as this picture from STS-86 indicates.  Russian requirements were not so generous and this fact caused issues for this crew (it was a mission to Mir).

[image]

Comment: huge range indeed, but everyone seems off track with the original intent of my question. What advantages do you get by sending a bigger person into space in pragmatic terms, all else being equal. Is a stronger person more useful (even though bigger doesn't necessarily mean stronger)? Are they more useful as a source of food in an emergency...  stuff like that.

Comment: I was trying to indicate that for Shuttle program I do not believe that size was a criterion for selection, as long as a person met the generous requirements.  In other words, the requirements were set such that anyone passing the gate was considered equally qualified.  But I cannot speak for other programs so I acknowledge that my answer is incomplete.

Comment: You made your point well, hence the +1. My question is hypothetical in that it assumes that you have a pool of equally qualified astronauts of different sizes already. Perhaps I should change my question a bit, but it's already been migrated once, and might end up being migrated to oblivion. And I need a logical answer because I've already told my brother in law that I'm not letting him in my space ship because he's too big. Which made me wonder what advantages there could be if I did allow him on my hypothetical spacecraft.

Comment: Edited my answer to address your real question. I would not expect a larger crewmember to be more useful as a net source of food; by the time you get around to cannibalism, the larger crewmember will have eaten more food relative to the smaller than you'd get back by eating him first. Also, planning for cannibalism suggests an overall lack of confidence in the mission.

Comment: Or could be a cultural thing, Polynesian emergency rations, but yes good point on the fact that he'd consume more than he's worth in that respect

Comment: I tried reverse image searching the inline image and was unable to find it. Could you add attribution and a link to details?

Comment: @OrganicMarble ditto - Are they astronauts? I so, who are the astronauts in the photo, and how tall are they? If not, never mind :)

Comment: This is Scott Parazynski (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_E._Parazynski) and Wendy Lawrence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendy_B._Lawrence). I worked with them on the Shuttle-Mir mission STS-86, this photo is from my personal collection.

Comment: Scott is 6'2", Wendy is 5'3".