# I'm two metres tall. Do I have a chance to be an astronaut?

Tags: astronauts

I am sixteen years old, athletic and **very** willing to learn to be an astronaut. The only problem is that I am two metres tall. While being tall is great in life, from what I have learned it isn't quite as great in a Soyuz capsule. Do you think I will ever have a chance to go to space? Or am I doomed to remain on Earth for the rest of my days?

Comment: Related:  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19963/how-tall-do-you-have-to-be-to-be-an-astronaut.  Unfortunately NASA says no, you're 7 cm too tall.

Comment: Who knows. Maybe the requirements to be an astronaut changes as time goes on.

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure it's a duplicate, since answers there only seem to apply to NASA and ISS. Since the OP has most of a century left to live and things are changing quickly, I don't think those answers apply to this question, which is cast in future tense: "Do you think I will ever have a chance to go to space?" So I would say that this question should not be closed as duplicate. I might be closable for another reason though (e.g. primarily opinion-based).

Comment: @Rob okay, that one might work for the OP, let's see...

Comment: @Rob I believe that the definition of duplicate in Stack Exchange lies solely on *whether the current question is answered on the other page*, not how similar the questions are. If this question is not sufficiently *answered* there, then we don't mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @Rob https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvSFd.png This is why we can't vote to close as duplicate of an unanswered question.

Comment: @uhoh The [heights of Americans and Russians](http://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/average-height-by-country/) are [sufficiently similar](https://www.theglobalist.com/striding-tall-us-vs-ussr/) that each can use each other's equipment.

Comment: @uhoh - The FAQ says: "[same **potential** answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/282094)".

Comment: @Rob right; *not* how similar the questions are.